# asp:Literal tag in <head> being rendered in <body>

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to place an asp:literal tag in my  element on a master page.  When I set the value in the code behind for the master page and then view a page that is using this master page, the value of the literal is output in the <body>.

I have the following Master Page:

```
 <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test1.master.cs" Inherits="Corporate.Presentation.Web.Test1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltlGoogleAnalytics"></asp:Literal>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;

namespace Corporate.Presentation.Web
{
    public partial class Test1 : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ltlGoogleAnalytics.Text = "test";
        }
    }
}
```

Test ASPX page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Test1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Corporate.Presentation.Web.TestForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

HTML Output:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>

</title></head><body>test


    <form method="post" action="TestForm1.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTY1NDU2MTA1Mg9kFgJmD2QWAgIBD2QWAgIBDxYCHgRUZXh0BQR0ZXN0ZGQVhLZ0Btj29J7NtToygADkXCPCuLkULTvV5jvIb8hFFw==">
</div>

    <div>


    </div>
    </form>


</body></html>
```

Comment: aspx control must be placed inside a form tag

Comment: What you want to do by placing literal in the head tag

Comment: its google analytics code that is coming from a CMS database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting actual script reference instead of putting the text. It will be placed in the head if you have proper content that is allowed in the head region as your literal text.

```
ltlGoogleAnalytics.Text = "<script src='/scripts/analytics.js' type='text/javascript'></script>"
```

Comment: You have a self-terminating end-tag at the end of your string. Was that intended?

Comment: Thanks, the code is stored in the database correctly, but it must be coming in as plain text, will look at encoding it correctly.

Comment: Yes, that shows that if the content is valid for head tag it will be present in head, otherwise, will be rendered in the body. :)